# Find the orthogonal projection of $f(x)=4x^2−4$ onto the subspace spanned by $g(x)=x−12$ and $h(x)=1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Use the inner product $\langle f,g\rangle =\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx$ in the vector space $C^0[0,1]$ to find the orthogonal projection of $f(x)=5x^2+4$ onto the subspace $V$ spanned by $g(x)=1$ and $h(x)=1$.

Comment: I found constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that C1∫f(x)f(x)dx = 1 and C2∫g(x)g(x)dx = 1 giving me C1 = $\frac{15}{128}$ and C2 = $\frac{12}{1}$

Comment: V = Span{g(x),h(x)} = ag(x)+ bh(x) for some constants a & b so that V = a(x-1/2) + b = cx + d for some constants c and d. 
So letting f(x) = cx + d or $C_2x + C_1$ is as you have it. 
Now to find an orthonormal basis we apply Gram-Schmidt process?

Comment: x-1/2, fixed it.

Comment: Is this like the formula $A*(A^T*A)^{-1}*A^T$?

Comment: You want $f(x)$ to be orthogonal to lower degree polynomials, so it looks like you can simply run Gram-Schmidt on the (ordered) basis $h(x),g(x),f(x)$. The polynomial $g(x)$ is already orthogonal to $h(x)$ (check this if you haven't done it yet). Therefore you need one more round of Gram-Schmidt:
$$\tilde{f}=f-\frac{\langle f,h\rangle}{\langle h,h\rangle}h-\cdots?$$

Answer (score 2):

We have:
$$\langle g,h\rangle = 0,\quad \langle g,g\rangle = \frac{1}{12},\quad \langle h,h\rangle = 1,$$
while:
$$ \langle f,g \rangle = \frac{1}{3},\quad \langle f,h \rangle = -\frac{8}{3},$$
hence the projection of $f$ on $\operatorname{Span}(g,h)$ is given by:
$$ f^{\perp} =4g-\frac{8}{3}h = 4x-\frac{14}{3}. $$